# How to have the container adjust to a GWT grid?

Tags: gwt, grid, containers

I have a DataGrid with a SimplePager and when theres less than the predefined number of rows per page (in this case 15) the container will show those rows and leave a white space in between the grid and the simplePager (where the other rows would be).

I have seen some mentions on other sites about rendering datagrid first and then fit it into the container, but i have no idea what this means (Or at least, i don't think they're saying its as easy as removing it from the parent and re-attaching it, since i've tried that already).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My proposition - resize container after data fetch, after rendering of grid. It will be just something like this:

```
container.setHeight(grid.getOffsetHeight() + "px");
```